# Elegant way to remove target file if a Make rule fails

Tags: shell, makefile, stdout, gnu-make, redirectstandardoutput

I have a rule in my Makefile that roughly looks like this:

```
target_file: src_file
        some_tool src_file > target_file
```

(Of course, in reality I'm using `$@` and `$<`, but for this question I prefer a more explicit style.)

The problem is that `target_file` is always created by the shell with a fresh timestamp, even if `some_tool` fails. In that case, an empty `target_file` exists, and even if I fix the underlying issue, it won't be rebuilt until I manually remove `target_file` or touch `src_file`.

Also, `some_tool` only writes to standard output, so I can't work around this through a cleaner approach such as `some_tool ... -o target_file`.

My current approach is to remove

```
target_file: src_file
        some_tool src_file > target_file || rm -f target_file
```

However, this has the disadvantage that `Make` won't notice if `some_tool` fails, because in that case `rm` takes over and returns exitcode 0 (succeess).

Another approach may be:

```
target_file: src_file
        some_tool src_file > target_file.tmp
        mv target_file.tmp target_file
```

But that kind of code is tedious and on failure leaves an annoying file `target_file.tmp` behind.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [special target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) `.DELETE_ON_ERROR`:

> If .DELETE_ON_ERROR is mentioned as a target anywhere in the makefile, then make will delete the target of a rule if it has changed and its recipe exits with a nonzero exit status, just as it does when it receives a signal.

All it takes is one line:

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```

And all rules that fail will have their target removed.

Comment: Thanks! This should be the default behavior in make.